# Making menu key invisible from bottom status bar | uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"

Tags: android, statusbar, android-menu

I am in a position where I have to use `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"` in manifest file. I have created my own custom action bar which is actually a `LinearLayout`. My position is such that I can not use action bar provided by Android, nether can extend it.

Now I have added custom menu key in my action bar (created using `LinearLayout`).

I want the menu Key to be invisible from bottom status bar.

I have tried returning `false` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` but it only disables the menu but still menu is shown in bottom status bar.

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this code in manifest file:

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
          android:targetSdkVersion="11"

It should work !

Answer (score 1):

Whether compatibility menu button shows up or not is figured out based on target API. Add

```
android:targetSdkVersion="14"
```

to your manifest to prevent it from showing up ever. You can leave `minSdkVersion` at `7`

Also, read [Say Goodbye To Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) carefully